# Какая программа кроме Скайпа может блокировать 80 порт при установке веб сервера?

Tags: windows

1. Какая программа, кроме Скайпа может блокировать 80 порт?
2. Какие стандартные программы Винды могут блокировать 80 порт?

Comment: 1) Апач (хоть от денвера). и не блокировать, а просто использовать.
2) Фаервол.

И вообще то это на руткод вопрос.

Comment: Проблема при установке апач. фаервола нет)

Comment: teamviewer

Comment: teamviewerа тоже нет.

Comment: еще какие программы?

Comment: Windows насколько понимаю, а какой именно?

И фаервол вроде как всегда есть - в 7-ке была проблема при указании сети как публичная, а не частная.

Там правда не с апачем косяк был, а с ТВ-плеером, но суть почти одна и та же - нужный порт не доступен.

А антивирус какой? Может там встроенный фаервол есть?

Comment: cmd > netstat -b

Comment: С каких это пор Skype работает по 80-му порту?

Comment: давно он уже любит его занимать. и ещё 443. Зайдите в настройки скайпа, Дополнительно->Соединение. Там есть галочка "использовать порты 80 и 443 для своих тайных целей".

Comment: windows 7, скайпа нет, teamviewerа тоже нет.

Comment: я-бы поправил: cmd > netstat -a -b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** Для тех, кому проще кликать:

`Ctrl+Shift+Esc -> Быстродействие -> Монитор ресурсов`
`Сеть -> Порты прослушивания`

Находите порт и инфу по программе, его занявшей.

**Вариант 2.** Для любителей черных экранов и зелёного текста:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :80
```

После чего, посмотреть PID и определить имя:

```
tasklist | findstr <PID>
```

Вместо `<PID>` прописать PID.

Comment: можно также 

    netstat -a -n

в консоли

Comment: Красавец. Отличный ответ!

Comment: @ArcherGodson, тогда уже:

    netstat -ano | findstr :80

После чего, посмотреть PID и определить имя:

    tasklist | findstr <PID>

Вместо <PID> прописать PID.

@exec, благодарю :)